# How to delete text to the end?

Tags: visual-studio, text, combobox, notepad++, notepad

I have a combo like this

```
adrian-strauch@t-online.de:12xxxxxx | 5
svenschalke@t-online.de:kikerxxx | 33
dennis.meinhardt@t-online.de:vxxxxxx | 169
Fabibau@t-online.de:rofxxxx | 134
anders.gerd@t-online.de:townxxx | 1
```

i want delete text after last "x" to end

i think my combo have 60,000 line

how can i do this ?

i try this in notepad ++ but not work

```
   use ctrl+h and type   " | /r "
```

but its not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the pipe between horizontal whitespace chars and match the last digits until the end of the string.

Select *Wrap around* and *Regular expression*

**Find what:**

```
\h+\|\h+\d+$
```

**Replace with**

Leave empty

---

*Explanation*

- `\h+` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `\|` Pipe
- `\h+` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xlggfm/1)

[image]

---

If you also want to match the newlines and there can also be something else except digits:

```
\h+\|\h+.*\R*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZuvtRx/1)